Does Databricks Spark persist data after the first read (outside of Spark cache)
Something I've been struggling to understand in Spark (specifically in Databricks), is Spark persisting data after the first read (in some storage format that isn't the cache)?
More specifically, when I run the following code in cell A
val rdd1 = spark.sql("Select STH from STH").rdd //reading from unity catalogue (azure datalake blob storage)
rdd1.count

And then immediately after, I run the count action again in cell B
rdd1.count

I get the following error

This error is only happening when converting from a data frame to an RDD. If I only work with data frames (as in I don't convert to RDD) everything works fine for some reason.
After a long process of trial and error, I found that if I persist the RDD in Disk Cache (or RAM) then I stop getting the error. So if I do the following:
So for example, when I do the following the problem disappears:
val rdd1 = spark.sql("Select STH from STH").rdd.persist(DISK_ONLY) // or MEMORY_ONLY
rdd1.count

This all makes me more inclined to think that the data is indeed being persisted even when I'm not explicitly asking for persistence. Otherwise, what is the reason that only the count in the first cell works when I don't explicitly persist the RDD? (In other words, why is it the case that the count only works the first time the table is actually scanned).

Are you using Azure databricks?

Yes sir, it's Azure Databricks.

spark usually wants the source be available/connected constantly on whole process like aws s3 or azure dfs, have you printed your spark configurations ?

Have you tried using .persist() or .cache()).

Spark manages lazy evaluation and data storage during computations, specifically focusing on RDDs and their interactions with the underlying storage layer.
When you do spark.sql("Select STH from STH").rdd it is related to lazy, means no computation occurs until an action (like count) is called.
When you perform an action like count on an RDD, Spark reads the data from the source (ADLS) and processes it.
If you do not persist the RDD, Spark will discard the data after the action is completed.
When you run the count action again, Spark attempts to read the data from the source again.
The below is the approach I have tried as an example:
val rdd2 = dilip_sampleData.rdd.persist(org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
println(s"Count: ${rdd2.count}")
println(s"Count from second action:: ${rdd2.count}")

Results:
Count: 4
Count from second action:: 4
rdd2: dilip_sampleData.rdd.type = MapPartitionsRDD[55] at rdd at command-3745231482926884:2



Thats clearly not the question I asked… I didnt ask whether or not evaluation is lazy in spark… I asked why reading fails on the second attempt but succeeds on the first attempt

@Nizar Can you provide information about how are you accessing the storage account have mounted your storage account or using access key?

You have posted an irrelevant answer so that you can receive the bounty... such a shame...

Note to reviewers: Answers which misunderstood the question are not Very Low Quality. The correct review is "Looks OK".

@EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine you're mistaken in my view. The author of the answer had commented on the question prior to posting their answer. And only posted the answer after the bounty was set; indicating that the main motive wasn't their understanding of the question and the desire to answer it. But the desire to gain bounty.
